# Можно ли в switch-case сверять с массивом?

Tags: php, массивы, switch

Возник такой вопрос. Пишу бота-помощника для сайта и нужно анализировать фразы посетителей, но их может быть великое множество вариаций, поэтому возник вопрос, а можно ли в `case` вместо одного значения поставить сразу массив и сравнивать с этим массивом ответов? И если хоть одно значение совпадет, выполнять этот `case`

Comment: кажется [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php), вполне ясно описывает синтаксис и возможности оператора `switch`. Приведите какой-нибудь пример кода, и возможно вам подскажут, как оптимизировать его написание

Comment: можно...но скорее всего нужно делать совсем другое.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Но это выглядит как не верный подход. Поиск совпадения в массиве достаточно затратная операция, а вы предлагаете искать в нескольких массивах. 
Если подойти к вопросу чисто академически, то код будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
$var = 'Hello';
$var = strtolower($var);
$array1 = array('hello', 'hi', 'yo');
$array2 = array('what', 'where', 'when');

switch (true) {
    case in_array($var, $array1):
        //do something
        break;
    case in_array($var, $array2):
        //do something else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Можете посоветовать способ делать это быстрей и менее затратно?

Comment: @So-so , я не знаком с вашей предметной областью, но мне кажется более подходящим вариантом использование легковесной базы данных, где поиск будет происходить по подготовленной фразе (strtolower, htmlspecialchars и подобное).

Если свести все вразы к ключам то можно использовать NoSQL решения, если нет то MySQL.